# What memory size per apache process is ridiculous?

Tags: apache, process, memory, prefork

(closetnoc, yes I come with interesting and maybe ridiculous questions, but...)

I have a question.

I'm trying to make my server run as wonderful as possible and I'm in the back-end. Ever since I optimized my PHP code, I managed to get my apache process (program memory use) size down from 80+ MB to around 45 MB.

But my question is, in a standard cPanel setup with a simple apache 2.2 server running in prefork mode, what memory size per apache process would be considered ideal and what memory size would be considered ridiculous? *I'm looking for the perfect range*

I ask because my server has 8 GB ram with 10 GB swap available and if I can make good use of the ram (by running as many apache processes as possible) whilst leaving some memory free for dirty data and touching nothing of swap, then I'm golden.

At this time I cannot use any mode other than prefork because I have my own apache module loaded (which used only the libraries presented to me when I crafted my code from the template generated from executing `apxs -g`), and also I use mod_php5 as well as mod_ruid2.

Comment: Actually, I like your questions! You are clearly digging in and thinking which is a heck of a lot more than most professionals. I do not know what to recommend. You are right to allocate memory for Apache and for any database cache (if you have not already). Just know there is always a hit to swap. The thing you are trying to prevent is swapping in and out of memory as much as possible. One trick is to have enough CPU (+cores) to allow processes to stay within the CPU longer and not be interrupted by a higher priority process. Allocating memory for Apache helps too.

Comment: As I'm digging, I notice that at least 2/3 of one of my apache processes memory is used by something called `[ anon ]`. I looked it up via `pmap` in linux.

Comment: I would have to poke around, I remember reading on anon a while ago. I  just do not remember. -- Just so that you know, the rule is that anything in memory must reside 2 times in permanent storage for stability. An executable exists on the hard drive, is executed, and is loaded into memory and swap. The original executable and swap are the 2 copies of permanent storage. It is possible, though fairly rare these days, that memory, CPU, and swap limitations will unload a process within the compute queue only to reload it again later. This is done through priority adjustments. Again very rare.

Comment: I guess my point is do not get carried away. I uped some values a whee bit too much and found that performance under load downgraded. Think of the times where your system is at it's peek. Also consider uping your database cache if you have not. I get more performance upgrade from this than Apache since this is the hardest hit against the HD even though it is smaller chunks. DB cache is intelligent enough that under load, it will improve performance and not downgrade it. I see this every time G crawls my site or when it gets busy otherwise.

Comment: I think my db caching is ok. about 300 MB ram is allocated to mysql. I'm gonna have to find myself some stress utilities. I tried apache bench but I don't know if thats accurate enough.

Comment: There is no perfect range and you should never use SWAP, most good hosts will disable it, its a MySQL/APACHE killer.

Comment: @SimonHayter Some memory allocations are outside of swap allocations. It all depends on how the code is written. For MySql cache, the allocation is outside of swap. I also believe that Apache caching is outside too, but not process run-up. For my MySql cache allocation, mine is about 2gig and has been set as high as 4gig. I am not a linux expert at all. Linux was originally written by DEC following the rules for OSes at the time and so when I reach back into the recesses being an exDEC internals engineer, that is what I come up with. I will differ to your expertise of course. Cheers!!

Comment: cPanel, MySQL and Apache by default will use the SWAP. Even if you set policies on processes there's nothing to say that they won't crash and ignore the allocation policy. The SWAP is merely an overflow of which it should NEVER be consumed in a server environment. When a process crashes it can cause memory overflows and will eat into all ram and all swap... your better of just letting that program die before it effects everything else. Apache/MySQL in SWAP is game over for busy servers. That's why 'GOOD' hosting companies disable SWAP period, especially on the cloud.

Comment: The only reason why I have swap enabled (even though I might only use it 1/100000th of a time when debugging the server) is because programs leak memory (particularly PHP on apache) and if swap is disabled and the system is out of memory (because of excessive leaking) then I'd likely be forced to restart the computer

Comment: If the SWAP gets used its pretty much as a good as a CRASH... because even a memory leak can and will eat the SWAP, your simply delaying it... Your better of fixing the issue by automatically killing memory leaks as they happen.

Comment: @SimonHayter You are right in that swap is not always necessary anymore with the amount of affordable memory that can be loaded into a server. Swap was originally designed for two things, backup for memory allocations (sanity check if memory were to get foobar'ed) and because there were more process allocations than memory available. Without swap, you cannot allocate more than you have. So for busy servers, the assumption is that there is a lot of memory available. For smaller sites, that may not always be the case. As well, the option may not be available for shared hosting.

Comment: I just noticed something rather surprising. Each apache process takes about 40 MB RSS ram, about 350 MB virtual memory and less than 10 MB shared memory. I looked at the free memory sections and noticed it did not go down much and I'm still not swapping after going from about 30 running apache processes to 95. I would think by then I would have maybe a few megs free memory, but I still have alot more. I don't get it.

Comment: @Mike you should be aware that Linux has built in OOM (Out of memory killer) that will kill processes when the server is out of memory... if you add a swap your simply have to wait until the SWAP is completely filled, which is silly because the server can become inaccessible as it will build up processing queues in both the SQL and Apache.

Comment: It's not windows, you should never use SWAP... :P Having a swap is pointless if you have the necessary things in place to stop the leaks in their tracks.

Comment: @SimonHayter that's why I post this question... to ensure I have the necessary things in place to avoid swap while pleasing the world (a.k.a. the correct number of apache processes)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about webmastering as per http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic